# How to make webview Android app not show adsense ads?

Tags: android, webview, adsense

I have made an android app showing a portion of my webpage in a webview. The problem is that the webpage has some adsense ads and it is not allowed to show them in an app.
So the question is : is there some way of making them a no show in the app?

the code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://androidomedia.com/angry-birds-space-walkthrough/");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

}

   private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
       @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
       {
           webview.loadUrl(url);
           return true;
       }
       }
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
   {
       if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
       {
           mWebView.goBack();
           return true;            
       }
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

   }
```

}`

Answer (score 1):

You could handle this on the server side assuming the content is generated dynamically.  Just have the web server not show the ad unit if the request is coming from your android app.  Explicity set the user agent on the android side and check for it when building your template.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set your User Agent string to something that you could easily detect like so:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("AndroidWebView");
```

Second, on the server that hosts your website, you need to dynamically generate the script that Google gave you. If you are using ASP.NET to host your website, you could do something such as this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

                //Ensure that the Adsense ad isn't loaded if the calling user is using a WebView
                if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("AndroidWebView"))
                {
                    return;
                }

                //Create the Google Adsense ad dynamically
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine("google_ad_client = \"ca-pub-123456789\";");
                sb.AppendLine("/* Ad Name Here */");
                sb.AppendLine("google_ad_slot = \"123456785\";");
                sb.AppendLine("google_ad_width = 728;");
                sb.AppendLine("google_ad_height = 90;");
                sb.Append("//-->");

                var scriptTag = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
                scriptTag.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
                scriptTag.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();

                var scriptTag2 = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
                scriptTag2.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
                scriptTag2.Attributes.Add("src", "http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js");

                phBigAd.Controls.Add(scriptTag);
                phBigAd.Controls.Add(scriptTag2);

    }
```

After that, add a PlaceHolder to your ASPX Mark-up page named phBigAd anywhere you want your ad to be on the site:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phBigAd" runat="server" />
```

Of course, you will need to replace the Adsense code with your own when appending to the StringBuilder, but the above is the general format that you would go by.